# Ember JS: Can I make my UI state persistent?

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-cli

I have off canvas navigation on the left and right of my ember application.

The state is controlled by a couple simple properties triggered by actions.

Template:

```
<a {{action 'leftToggle'}} class="left-blade">Debtor List</a>
<a {{action 'rightToggle'}} class="right-blade">Acivity</a>
```

Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isLeft: false,
    isRight: false,

    actions: {
        leftToggle: function() {
            this.toggleProperty('isLeft');
        },
        rightToggle: function() {
            this.toggleProperty('isRight');
        }
    }
});
```

I would like these properties to persist across page reloads, or if a user navigates away and then comes back to the page.

I am not sure whether to store the properties in a model? or use localStorage, or what?  It would seem like using a model just to store a simple thing like that is overkill, or if there is a better way?  I am still learning ember, so I would like to learn a good habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly out of the scope of Ember.

Persisting data happens in a few places, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `cookie`, `url`, or some sort of record persisted server side and fetched/updated client side.

This is really a pick your poison, you could attempt to use the Ember's new `query-params` feature and tack the state onto the url, which would involve Ember the most, but isn't necessarily the best option.  Local storage seems just as easy to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, does ember have a method for passing state *to* one of these storage methods? or am I going to do some research outside of ember?

Comment: Ember Data (different product) has some third party adapters that support local storage, beside that local storage is a key/value dictionary.  It's fairly simple to interact with.

Comment: That is great! I just realized that Ember-Data is included with my CLI build, so I will learn about that and also look up HTML5 localStorage.